# WPF - Query string parameters on page

Tags: wpf, query-string, querystringparameter

I am very new to WPF and have what appears to be a simple question:

I have a Frame and I set the Source to the Uri of one of my pages.  I want to pass some query string parameters to the page, but I am not sure how to access them in the Loaded event of the Page.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:
NavigationService.CurrentSource will give you the Uri of the current page that you are on and you can grab the query string parameters from that.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this related StackOverflow question:
[Passing parameters to a WPF Page via its Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351546/passing-parameters-to-a-wpf-page-via-its-uri)

[Paul Stovell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351546/passing-parameters-to-a-wpf-page-via-its-uri/1544558#1544558) explains a better approach for passing data than using a query string.