# Load xaml Page as Frame's Source with parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a xaml Page with class parameters:

```
public partial class result : Page
{
    public result(string inpH1, string inpH2, string inpH3, string inpText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ....
     }
```

I want to add the page into a stackpanel:

```
Frame neu = new Frame();
neu.Source = new System.Uri("result.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
stackpanel1.Children.Add(neu);
```

My question is, how can I write my parameter in Uri?

My code works without parameters perfect, but I have no idea how to call it with parameters

Comment: Why `new Frame()` and not `new result(...)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to a WPF Page via its Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351546/passing-parameters-to-a-wpf-page-via-its-uri)

Comment: @Bizhan: is not exactly the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set the `Source` to a `Uri` to create an instance of your `result` class but you can set the `Content` property to an instance that you create yourself using the custom constructor:

```
Frame neu = new Frame();
neu.Content = new result("a", "b", "c", "d");
stackpanel1.Children.Add(neu);
```